# Call a function when autocomplete text is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Hello I did build a autocomplete text field for my project:

HTML Coding:

```
<!-- Autocomplete Function -->
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender"  runat="server" CompletionSetCount="10" TargetControlID="input_source" 
ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" MinimumPrefixLength="1"> 
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>

 <!--Inputfield Autocomplete-->
 <asp:TextBox autocomplete="on" id="input_source" OnTextChanged="input_source_TextChanged" runat ="server"  class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code behind C#:

```
//Autocomplete Field
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = lr_sqlserver;


        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
        {
            com.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 5 Source FROM" + " " + selected_table + " " + "WHERE Source like '%' + @Search + '%'";

            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", prefixText);
            com.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    suggestions.Add(sdr["Source"].ToString());
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            return suggestions;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to call the following function everytime I select a suggestion from the autocomplete function. Is something like this possible?

```
protected void input_source_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string source = input_source.Text;

    using (
        SqlConnection com = new SqlConnection())
        {
        //SQL Server
        com.ConnectionString = lr_sqlserver;

        //Conncection establish
        com.Open();

        //Get SQL Information
        SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("select target from " + selected_table + " where source = @param", com);
        select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", source);
        string result;
        result = (string)select.ExecuteScalar();

        if (result != null)
        {
            input_target.Text = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to put your TextBox inside an UpdatePanel and on the TextBox set AutoPostBack="True"

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox autocomplete="on" id="input_source" OnTextChanged="input_source_TextChanged" runat ="server"  class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox> 
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: When I try to use it. It shows me this:  Server Error in '/' Application.
Parser Error
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' does not have a public property named 'TextBox'.                     Okay I added the <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate> tags and now the error is gone. I am going to test it now